# How to resolve this Incremental loading with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my first time make a post in here and appreciate any suggestion first!

Basically, I got two tables that one is Incremental table and the other is Final table.

In the First day loading, Incremental table is like below

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |

Therefore, Final table was empty firstly and then loaded the record from Incremental into Final table

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |

However, in the Second day, the Incremental table got changed.

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D |

So that the Final table should be like this.

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | C |

If there are same ID in both Incremental and Final, the Incremental should replace all the same ID, such as ID = 1 got replaced with Incremental table.
If the ID only in the Final table but not in the Incremental table, it would keep the same row, such as ID = 2

And **my goal** is to make a query to **find out the removed record**

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |

(Each row can be view as unique row in both Incremental and Final table. And everyday each ID its Code could be changed, so that I need to update with the latest Code.)

I'm struggling with this issue for five days long and I can make a query for finding out Second day removed record, but it would have some issue on First day loading.(I'm writing this with PostgreSQL)

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Comment: is this not just `delete final from incremental join final using (ID); insert into final select * from incremenal` ?

Comment: Hi - are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? Please update your tags to show the actual DBMS you are using. If your DBMS supports it then just use a MERGE statement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function or T-SQL procedure which can have below 2 queries.

Delete * from FINAL where ID in  ( select distinct ID from INCREMENTAL);

Insert into FINAL (Select Id, Code from INCREMENTAL;

These are just rough queries bu should give you basic idea

Edit :
To get the records which are going to get removed, you can add one more sql statement **before Delete statement** as

Insert into SOME_OTHER_TABLE (Select * from FINAL where ID in  ( select distinct ID from INCREMENTAL));

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I will either delete this answer, or refactor it to be in Postgres syntax (I initially misread the question and thought this was for SQL Server). Depending on whether it answers the question or not. Currently the question is ambiguous.

This answer takes advantage of the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause available in SQL Server. However, this is not necessary just seems a bit cleaner.

I would prefer to see some notion of a primary key on this data, but I'll assume you have a good reason for what you are doing. However, this answer is predicated on the assumption that the ID column can NOT be NULL.

Create relevant tables, and load inital data.

```
--simulate your incremental table ,I have called this Staging
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Staging;
CREATE TABLE Staging (ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                        , Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                        );
                        
INSERT INTO Staging(ID
                    , Code
                    )
VALUES(1, 'A')
    , (1, 'B')
    , (2, 'C');
    
    
--simulate your next table (final table). I've called this Persisted
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Persisted;
CREATE TABLE Persisted(ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                        , Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                        );
                                            
--Create a table to store the deletions
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PersistedDeletes
CREATE TABLE PersistedDeletes(ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                            , Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                            , DeletedOn DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL
                            );
```

Next we define a procedure to move data from Staging to Persisted in the manner you've described.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadStagingToPersisted
AS
BEGIN
    --Two Atomic DML operations are happening to Persisted. 
    --So let's wrap this in a transaction
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        --Compare Staging with Persisted
        CREATE TABLE #Comparison(ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                            , InSourceNotInTarget BIT NOT NULL
                            , InTargetNotInSource BIT NOT NULL
                            , InBothSourceAndTarget BIT NOT NULL
                            );
    
        INSERT INTO #Comparison(ID
                            , InSourceNotInTarget
                            , InTargetNotInSource
                            , InBothSourceAndTarget
                            )
        --Assumption 1: ID is never NULL. so it can only be NULL via a left/right join
        SELECT COALESCE(src.ID, tgt.ID) AS ID
            , CASE 
                WHEN tgt.ID IS NULL 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS InSourceNotInTarget
            , CASE 
                WHEN src.ID IS NULL 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS InTargetNotInSource
            , CASE 
                WHEN src.ID IS NOT NULL AND tgt.ID IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS InBothSourceAndTarget
        FROM Persisted tgt
        FULL JOIN Staging src
            ON tgt.ID = src.ID

        --Delete from Persisted all IDs which match between Staging and Persisted.
        --Output the deleted rows into the table PersistedDeletes.
        DELETE per
        OUTPUT DELETED.ID
            , DELETED.Code
            , GETDATE()
        INTO PersistedDeletes
        FROM Persisted per
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ID 
            FROM #Comparison
            WHERE InBothSourceAndTarget = 1
            GROUP By ID
            ) del
            ON per.ID = del.ID
        ;


        --Now we insert all the new records, as well as those that replace the previous deletes.
        INSERT INTO Persisted(ID
                            , Code
                            )
        SELECT src.ID
            , src.Code
        FROM Staging src
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM #Comparison
            WHERE InSourceNotInTarget = 1
                OR InBothSourceAndTarget = 1
            GROUP BY ID
            ) ins
            ON src.ID = ins.ID;
    COMMIT
END;
```

Finally, use this procedure to load the data from Staging to Persisted. Then reload Staging with some new data, and run the procedure again.

```
--Load Persisted
EXEC LoadStagingToPersisted;
SELECT * FROM Persisted;

--simulate the next state of Staging
TRUNCATE TABLE Staging;
INSERT INTO Staging(ID
                , Code
                )
VALUES (1, 'D');

--Load Persisted again
EXEC LoadStagingToPersisted;
SELECT * FROM Persisted;
--Also check what was deleted
SELECT * FROM PersistedDeletes;
```

Play around with the inputs yourself to confirm if this does what you want it to. Try it yourself here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YzBRaT0f)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your initial table (your incremental table) is insert only and has an additional column to track the timestamp when a record was inserted. Also assuming that when you say the 'latest' record that you are referring to the IDs that have the greatest insert timestamp.

The capturing of deletes can be inserted into another table by way of a trigger.

The process requires deleting from your final table, and then inserting into it. as these are two atomic operations, I'd recommend you make sure they are both happening in the one transaction. I'm not familiar enough with Postgres to know if this is the default behaviour inside a procedure or not.

I have called your 'Incremental' table Staging, your 'Final' table Persisted, and the table which stores the deletes is 'PersistedDeletes'.

First create the necessary tables, trigger and function called by the trigger.

```
--simulate your incremental table ,I have called this Staging
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Staging (ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                        , Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                        , InsertedOn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
                        );
                        
INSERT INTO Staging(ID
                    , Code
                    )
VALUES(1, 'A')
    , (1, 'B')
    , (2, 'C');

SELECT * FROM Staging;
    

--simulate your next table (final table). I've called this Persisted    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persisted(ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                        , Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                        );
                                            
--Create a table to store the deletions
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PersistedDeletes(ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                            , Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
                            , DeletedOn TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
                            );
                            
--Create a function to insert deleted rows into PersistedDeletes
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION InsertPersistedDeletes() 
RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PersistedDeletes(ID
                                , Code
                                , DeletedOn
                                )
    SELECT OLD.ID
        , OLD.Code
        , NOW();
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--create a trigger to call the function when a row is deleted from Persisted.
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER InsertPersistedDeletes 
AFTER DELETE ON Persisted 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION  InsertPersistedDeletes();
```

Then we define a procedure to load data in the manner you have specified

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LoadStagingToPersisted()
AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    /*Compare latest records in Staging with Persisted
    Easiest to store this in a table, as we need to use it twice.
    */
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_comparison;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_comparison(ID BIGINT NOT NULL
                                    , InSourceNotInTarget BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                                    , InTargetNotInSource BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                                    , InBothSourceAndTarget BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                                    );
    INSERT INTO tmp_comparison(ID
                            , InSourceNotInTarget
                            , InTargetNotInSource
                            , InBothSourceAndTarget
                            )
    --Get the most recently inserted record for each ID in Staging. i.e. the latest record.
    WITH LatestRecords
    AS
    (
        SELECT MAX(InsertedOn) AS MaxInsertOn
            , ID
        FROM Staging
        GROUP BY ID
    )
    SELECT COALESCE(src.ID, trg.ID) AS ID
            , CASE 
                WHEN trg.ID IS NULL 
                THEN True
                ELSE False
            END AS InSourceNotInTarget
            , CASE 
                WHEN src.ID IS NULL 
                THEN True
                ELSE False
            END AS InTargetNotInSource
            , CASE 
                WHEN src.ID IS NOT NULL AND trg.ID IS NOT NULL 
                THEN True
                ELSE False
            END AS InBothSourceAndTarget 
    FROM LatestRecords src
    FULL JOIN Persisted trg
        ON src.ID = trg.ID;

    DELETE
    FROM Persisted
    USING (
        SELECT per.ID
        FROM Persisted per
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM tmp_comparison
            WHERE InBothSourceAndTarget = True
            GROUP BY ID -- You won't need to do this if ID, InsertOn is unique in the Staging table...
            ) cmp
            ON per.ID = cmp.ID
        ) del
    WHERE del.ID = Persisted.ID;

    INSERT INTO Persisted(ID
                        , Code
                        )
    SELECT src.ID
        , src.Code
    FROM Staging src
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM tmp_comparison
        WHERE InSourceNotInTarget = True
            OR InBothSourceAndTarget = True
        GROUP BY ID -- You won't need to do this if ID, InsertedOn is unique in the Staging table...
        ) cmp
        ON src.ID = cmp.ID;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Use the procedure to load Persisted, and then check the state of Persisted. Reload Staging with new data, then use the procedure to load Persisted again. Finally, check the state of Persisted and PersistedDeletes.

```
--Load Persisted
CALL LoadStagingToPersisted();
SELECT * FROM Persisted;

--simulate the next state of Staging
TRUNCATE TABLE Staging;
INSERT INTO Staging(ID
                , Code
                )
VALUES (1, 'D');

--Load Persisted again
CALL LoadStagingToPersisted();
SELECT * FROM Persisted;
--Also check what was deleted
SELECT * FROM PersistedDeletes;
```

Try it yourself: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i00Nk64y)

It is not particularly clear what you mean by loading the latest Codes for each ID. Whether latest depends on the time the records arrived into Staging, or when the process was run to move them into Persisted. I think that this answer is probably what you want, but if not check my other answer.